# How to delete file as if it was deleted, but not delete it actually in Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, delete-file

How to delete file from repo, remove it from tracking and ignore it?

```
git rm --cached -r myfile
```

doesn't help. File is likely removed, but I can't commit working copy and can't push to remote repo.

It says

```
Commit failed with error
        0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: AGAIN: removed `myfile` from version control
        On branch mybranch
        Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mybranch'.
```

---

What I do now is copying file to another place, then removing it from project with git, then committing, then copying back to place. Is it possible to automate?

Comment: What command are you using to make a new commit? The Git source code does not contain the string `failed to commit`.

Comment: Sorry, this message is from IntelliJ...

Comment: Anyway, command line hints are appreciated.

Comment: IntelliJ seems to take over a lot of things, so I can't say why that one is failing. From the command line, what you did, followed by `git commit`, should work. You might also want to add that path name to `.gitignore` so that Git does not complain about it being untracked afterward, and so that `git add --all` doesn't add it again.

Comment: just use `rm your_file`

Answer (score 0):

Force remove this file and add the change to staging area.

```
rm -f <file>
git add -A
git commit -m "message here…"
git push origin master
```